# In a 3 columns page, having the third column fixed when scrollbars appears

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 columns page where first and third columns are fixed. When my page have scrollbars, I would like to have the third column fixed. This mean when used scroll the page, I would like the third column to stay in place. Do you think it is possible?

Here is a jsfiddle with my current CSS & HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/f9eYx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `position: fixed;` to your sidebar CSS. [I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/f9eYx/3/).